# WPF Application crashes on startup

Tags: wpf, crash

After computer restart when I immediately starts wpf application it crashes with the following stack traces, unable to find the reason why it crahes , I have done exception handling at all places.

Note: This issue is not reproducible all the time.

[image].

Comment: Check your xaml. May be some references are missing.

Comment: Did you override OnStartup method or App constructor?

Comment: No, I didn't. @ValeraScherbakov

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your App.xaml?